Angular: How to Bind Select Option Values from Service Array in Template with @for Loop?
I have service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WeatherCardsService {
  constructor() {}

  selectedRegionInService: string = '';
  selectedCityInService: string = '';

  citiesArrays: string[] = ['Warsaw', 'New York', 'Tokyo'];
  regionArrays: string[] = [
    'Europe',
    'Asia',
    'North America',
    'South America',
    'Oceania',
    'Africa',
  ];

and a select in form:
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <label for="" class="text-xl font-semibold">Choose a region</label>
      <select
        name="region"
        id="region"
        class="w-[10rem] bg-transparent border-2 border-black rounded-full px-3 py-1 my-2 font-semibold text-center"
        [(ngModel)]="weatherCardsService.regionArrays"
      >
        @for(region of weatherCardsService.regionArrays; track region){ }
        <option [value]="region" class="p-3">
          {{ region }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>

i want to bind value of select in a form with a value in a service;
but the @loop doesnt work and i get the error:
Property 'region' does not exist on type 'WeatherFormComponent'.

in form component ts i have only:
 constructor(public weatherCardsService: WeatherCardsService) {}


Please provide an example from https://stackblitz.com. At first glance, your options aren't even in the for loop. Also what is city? there is no city variable anywhere.

The problem is the position of the { }. The tag options should be enclosed by them: @for(...){<option..></option>}

You don't want to bind to the array. You want to bind the value to a different property in the service or component (depending on how you want it to work). In your case, you need to bind to weatherCardsService.selectedRegionInService not the array.
Note: Your option is outside of the @for loop.
Here is a working example.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="weatherCardsService.selectedRegionInService">
      @for(region of weatherCardsService.regionArrays; track region) { 
        <option [value]="region">
          {{ region }}
        </option>
      }
    </select>
    Selected Region: {{weatherCardsService.selectedRegionInService}}
  `
})
export class App {
  selectedRegion: string = '';

  constructor(protected weatherCardsService: WeatherCardsService) {}
}

